# PHP: Why is browser output appearing at top of page?

Tags: php, html, css, foreach

I'm grabbing a number from a form on an html file, the current goal now is to simply output the range of numbers. But, they're appearing above my h1 header, at the top of the screen vs under the h1 tag. I've come across this before but can't for the life of me remember what the problem is.

```
<?php
$input = $_GET["number"];
$range = range(0, $input);
$output = pingpong($range);

function pingpong($fx_range)
{
  foreach ($fx_range as $number) {
    echo $number . ", ";
  }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ping Pong</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Ping Pong Results</h1>
      <?= $output . " "; ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output looks like this:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,

       Ping Pong Results
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you are using `echo` in your function which is before your HTML starts, and hence, the issue.

Comment: Because you're echoing in the `pingpong()` function, which is called before your markup

Comment: And you're assigning *nothing* to `$output =` - because that's what your function `return`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this instead:

```
<?php
$input = $_GET["number"];
$range = range(0, $input);
//$output = pingpong($range);

function pingpong($fx_range)
{
  foreach ($fx_range as $number) {
    echo $number . ", ";
  }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ping Pong</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Ping Pong Results</h1>
      <?php pingpong($range); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

Just to show you a way you can return an array from your function and through foreach output the values in HTML:

```
<?php
$input =$_GET["number"];
$range = range(0, $input);
$output = pingpong($range);

function pingpong($fx_range)
{
  foreach ($fx_range as $number) {
    $result[] = $number;
  }
  return $result;
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ping Pong</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Ping Pong Results</h1>
      <?php foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
            echo $value.',';
      } ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Holy Christ that worked!! Thank you. None of the other suggestions above where cluing me in, since they assumed I was able to figure it out from their hints. But this clarifies a lot. But, can you explain why my method wouldn't work? I've done this same format before, but with IF/else and return (not an echo) where I simply outputted a variable that was equal to the function with input like <h3><?= $yourFortune; ?></h3> and it worked.

Comment: @Padawan Your problem was you never assigned the values from the function to  $output. Always use return in functions. So the output you saw in the top of the screen, was because your function was running op there in your $output=pingpong($range) line, echo'en out the results. Also I would recommend collecting all the values in that function (0,1,2,3,4 etc) in an array and then return this array to  use outside of the function. I hope that makes sense, else feel free to ask again.

Comment: "Always use return in functions." Crap! I didn't know that. I tried, but only got '0' as an output, killing the loop, so resorted to echo. I'm missing a fundamental somewhere. I thought of an array, but didn't know how to grab html input and shove into an array. Will start all over again with your advice. Thank you for the 5 min mentoring. Much appreciated here...as I'm always scared to post on SO due to traditional, humiliating responses.

Comment: @Padawan no problem at all. When assigning the output from a function to a variable, you should use return. To output the values of an array to HTML, you would still need to loop through the array. I will update my answer to show you in a sec. It might not make much sense in this case - but the reason you only got 0 when you assigned the output from the function when using return, is because it only got the first value of the loop - so placing all the values in an array and then returning that array, it will give you all the values.

Comment: "When assigning the output from a function to a variable, you should use return." See, little statements like this are friggin' gold! You don't find them in tutorials or manuals or documentation. Only from those who know. Ok, thanks! I'll try to push to an array and loop through it, though still concerned about using return and killing the loop. Thanks again. Will hammer on this problem till I can do it inside and out.

Answer (score 1):

You run your function **pingpong()** that print to your screen and **var $output = NULL**

```
<?php
$input = $_GET["number"];
$range = range(0, $input);
**$output = pingpong($range); **  (the problem here)

function pingpong($fx_range)
{
  foreach ($fx_range as $number) {
    **echo $number . ", ";**  (the problem here)
  }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

You just should put it to variable  or to array

I would do it different way:

```
<?php
$input = $_GET["number"];
$range = range(0, $input);
$output = pingpong($range);

function pingpong($fx_range)
{
  foreach ($fx_range as $number) {
    $var[] = $number;
  }
  return $var;
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ping Pong</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Ping Pong Results</h1>
      <?= implode(', ',$output) ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

with implode you get cleaner result without ", " at the end.
and you don't need to run multiple loops
if you want to have different sort output you can do it very easy with array sort functions.

Comment: Thanks Meir. I actually ended up doing what you suggested pushing each $number into an $array[], but the implode wouldn't have worked for me since this was a preliminary step to just get an output. This is actually a FizzBuzz task, the end goal was to change each # divisible by 3 into Ping and each # div by 5 into Pong, and #s div by 3 & 5 changed to Ping Pong. So, I believe I needed the loops. Thanks for the feedback and the explanation. It's very helpful.